# How to Block a user in PHP this is my code

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the code which I am trying to block a user from my website. I am using MySQL database and I insert a **Banned** column in my user table and set their value **1** by default so tell me what I have to do. Table name of this section in MySQL database is **Lectures** So please help me as soon as possible.

```
 <?php
    session_start(); 
    include("header.php"); 
    include("conection.php");

    //echo "lec name".$_SESSION["lecname"];

    ?>
    <?php
    if($banned == "1")
    {
        header("Location:lectureaccount.php");
    }
    else
    {   
        header("Location:banned.php");
    }?>
    <?php
    //if(isset($_SESSION["userid"]))
    {
        $lec_id = $_SESSION["userid"];
?>
```

Comment: what problem are you getting?

Comment: As to answer your question directly. Your code is fine. Secondly, $banned means banned or allowed? as a common practice 1=true and 0=false.

Comment: I dont see an error here. Wheres your problem?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to redirect the user lectureaccount.php if $banned != 1, not equal to 1?

Comment: I think he wants us to write the MYSQL query on how to select banned.

Comment: What's the problem here ? Update your question. I would just suggest to use FALSE or 0 for users that are not banned as 1 can be confusing

Comment: He just registered now, so I doubt he will get to read our comments, or update his question or give us any feedback.

Comment: always after `header:("Location.....` redirects add a `die();` because user can bypass the redirect and continue to your code, in this example, browse the site which he isn't allowed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are doing good.

I am assuming you need to know what your SQL should be to get user data from the database.

```
<?php
session_start(); 
include("header.php"); 
include("conection.php");

//echo "lec name".$_SESSION["lecname"];

 if(isset($_SESSION["userid"]))
{
    $user_id = $_SESSION["userid"];

    $con=mysqli_connect("example.com","username","password","database_name");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT banned FROM Lectures where user_id = ".$user_id);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $banned= $row['banned'];
    }

    mysqli_close($con);

    if($banned == "1"){
        header("Location:lectureaccount.php");
    }
    else{   
        header("Location:banned.php");
    }
}

?>
<?php
//if(isset($_SESSION["userid"]))
{
    $lec_id = $_SESSION["userid"];
```